# Is "plain.fmt" equal "plain.tex" in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

When `tex` was input in terminal, there is `preloaded format=tex`. Is `preloaded format=tex` equal `plain.tex`? When input `&plain \input story` after the `tex` command, there is

```
Sorry, I can't find the format `plain.fmt'; will try `tex.fmt'.
```

What is the `tex.fmt`? Why didn't `&plain` call the `plain.tex`? What did the `&plain` call? If use the `plain.tex` as default, what should we change `&plain \input story` to?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149597/discussion-on-question-by-y-zeng-is-plain-fmt-equal-plain-tex-in-tex); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If on the commandline you use what the texbook calls `initex` but these days is not a separate program but `tex --ini` then you can see the steps in action.

```
tex --ini  plain
```

This will input plain.tex and process all the macros in there ending at the `*` prompt waiting for more input.

```
$ tex --ini plain.tex
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) (INITEX)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex))
*
```

At this point you can enter `\dump` and a binary dump of the state of tex's internal memory at this point is dumped to a file.

```
Beginning to dump on file plain.fmt
 (preloaded format=plain 2023.11.9)
2022 strings of total length 29204
4991 memory locations dumped; current usage is 110&4878
926 multiletter control sequences
\font\nullfont=nullfont
\font\tenrm=cmr10
\font\preloaded=cmr9
\font\preloaded=cmr8
\font\sevenrm=cmr7
\font\preloaded=cmr6
\font\fiverm=cmr5
\font\teni=cmmi10
\font\preloaded=cmmi9
\font\preloaded=cmmi8
\font\seveni=cmmi7
\font\preloaded=cmmi6
\font\fivei=cmmi5
\font\tensy=cmsy10
\font\preloaded=cmsy9
\font\preloaded=cmsy8
\font\sevensy=cmsy7
\font\preloaded=cmsy6
\font\fivesy=cmsy5
\font\tenex=cmex10
\font\preloaded=cmss10
\font\preloaded=cmssq8
\font\preloaded=cmssi10
\font\preloaded=cmssqi8
\font\tenbf=cmbx10
\font\preloaded=cmbx9
\font\preloaded=cmbx8
\font\sevenbf=cmbx7
\font\preloaded=cmbx6
\font\fivebf=cmbx5
\font\tentt=cmtt10
\font\preloaded=cmtt9
\font\preloaded=cmtt8
\font\preloaded=cmsltt10
\font\tensl=cmsl10
\font\preloaded=cmsl9
\font\preloaded=cmsl8
\font\tenit=cmti10
\font\preloaded=cmti9
\font\preloaded=cmti8
\font\preloaded=cmti7
\font\preloaded=cmu10
\font\preloaded=cmmib10
\font\preloaded=cmbsy10
\font\preloaded=cmcsc10
\font\preloaded=cmssbx10
\font\preloaded=cmdunh10
\font\preloaded=cmr7 at 14.51799pt
\font\preloaded=cmtt10 at 14.4pt
\font\preloaded=cmssbx10 at 14.4pt
\font\preloaded=manfnt
14787 words of font info for 50 preloaded fonts
14 hyphenation exceptions
Hyphenation trie of length 6075 has 181 ops out of 35111
  181 for language 0
No pages of output.
Transcript written on plain.log.
```

You now have a `plain.fmt` in your current directory.

If you use `&plain` that will get loaded and so TeX's internal state will be restored to the point of the `\dump` *without* having to read `plain.tex` again

```
$ tex '&plain' story
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=plain)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/plain/knuth-lib/story.tex [1])
*\bye
Output written on story.dvi (1 page, 680 bytes).
Transcript written on story.log.
```

Modern Tex is set up to use a default format based on the name of the program so the program `tex` needs a default format `tex.fmt`  the texlive build setup renames `plain.fmt` to `tex.fmt` so that this works and so `plain.fmt` does not normally exist, however if you try to use it there is a special case added,so that it uses `tex.fmt` anyway, with the warning that you showed.

Comment: Usually there is still a link from `initex` to `tex` and `tex` automatically behaves like `tex --ini` if the name is `initex`. So you can still run `initex`.

Comment: @cabohah ah true, yes (not sure about windows though, does that have a copy, if it doesn't really have links?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's not a link,but a thin wrapper binary

Answer (score 6):

In the olden times, TeX (the executable) came in two variants, namely `initex` and `virtex`.

The former variant had different memory allocation settings, mostly in order to deal with packaging hyphenation patterns into an efficient internal structure and was used to build formats.

For example, the command line

```
initex '\input plain \dump'
```

would have produced a file called `plain.fmt` so that you could later call

```
virtex "&plain" <filename>
```

to process your input file. And no, `plain.tex` and `plain.fmt` aren't the same: the latter is a binary file that can be digested fastly than inputting `plain.tex` and massaging the hyphenation patterns at runtime.

Later, people found out how to produce an executable that had already predigested `plain.fmt`, so allowing for even faster startup. The executable started to be called simply `tex`. Note that this procedure is OS dependent, so it had to be tailored for different machines and operating systems.

Eventually, with the introduction of the `kpathsea` library, a standard started to emerge and essentially every Unix-like operating system came to use the teTeX distribution, based on that library.

The idea that became very fruitful was not having a separate executable for every known format, say plain TeX, LaTeX, AMS-TeX, zzTeX, lollipop and more, but instead giving `virtex` the ability to load the proper `.fmt` file based on the name it is called with. So, for instance, `latex` was made into symbolic link to `virtex`, so this executable would actually run

```
virtex "&latex"
```

loading `latex.fmt`, but more transparently to users. And instead of `virtex` the executable started to be simply called `tex`, so instead of `initex` producing `plain.fmt` it was designed to produce `tex.fmt`.

However, in order to be “compatible” with the TeXbook, the `tex` executable might also try to use `tex.fmt` when called like

```
tex "&plain"
```

Not on the current TeX Live, it seems; my experiment tells me that TeX Live stopped doing this with the 2019 release. Maybe MiKTeX still does this.